# Access a CollectionView's layout properties in Layout object

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have implemented a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout, which only overrides one method `func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint`. In this method, I intend to access the current layout properties of already rendered collectionview eg: itemSize, sectionInsets etc.

However, when I try to access it like `self.itemSize`, it returns a default value.

Apple Docs asks the CollectionView Delegate to implement a corresponding delegate method for each of these properties eg:

> If the delegate does not implement the  collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: method, the flow layout object uses the value of this property to set the margins for each section.

I have implemented all these delegate methods in my View Controller.

Now my question is that don't these values set the underlying CollectionViewFlowLayout's object's properties? Does it always check for, if delegate responds to the specific corresponding selector and avoids storing that value in respective properties?

Is this the right way to access layout properties in collectionview's flow object?

```
let delegate = self.collectionView!.delegate as! UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
let itemSize = delegate.collectionView(<#T##collectionView: UICollectionView##UICollectionView#>, layout: <#T##UICollectionViewLayout#>, sizeForItemAt: <#T##IndexPath#>)
```

If yes, why is this such a long winded approach? If no, What am I missing?

Comment: `minimumInteritemSpacing` is a property on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` You can access it directly from within your subclass by saying `self.minimumInteritemSpacing`. `self.collectionView?.delegate` is of type `UICollectionViewDelegate` not `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and down casting will almost always fail. It's not advisable to force unwrap and force downcast in this situation.

Comment: Hey @beyowulf, the problem is it is always returning the default value. And thanks I have updated the type casting to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

If all of the cells are the same size then you should set `itemSize` and not use the delegate method. You can set this in interface builder by selecting your collection view, selecting the size inspector and setting the cell size. Or you can set this early in your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass's lifecycle.

If cells are dynamic in size, then you'll need to call the delegate method to determine the size. You're correct that you'll need to access the `delegate` through the collection view. This is likely done because `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` extends `UICollectionViewDelegate`. Adding a helper accessor like:

```
var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout? {
    return collectionView?.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
}
```

can make this easier to work with.

However, you should really only need to ask the delegate for sizing information when the layout is invalid. It seems like `layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)` or `layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)` could be used to determine size information for items that have already been laid out. Both of which are methods on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.